# Connecting react front end and express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

The dev build works fine, with my react app on port 3000 and server on port 8080. The front end is able to make requests to the backend and get the response.
But when deploying the production build, the application starts on port 5000 and the static files are rendered.But the front end can't access localhost:8080/api/:id because that port isn't 'on'.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to define custom config variables and [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package to define an environment for your react application. First install these packages.

```sh
yarn add dotenv && yarn add cross-env --dev
```

or

```sh
npm i dotenv && npm i cross-env --dev
```

You need create two separate .env config files, name them as `.env.development` and `.env.production`. Your env file may contain something like this:

**.env.development**

```
API_URL="localhost:8080"
```

**.env.production**

```
API_URL="localhost:5000"
```

Now on your react's `main.js` file(or what you have named), just import the `dotenv` package as follows:

```js
// other imports here
require('dotenv').config({ 
  path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/path/to/.env.production' : '/path/to/.env.development'
})
```

Now, on your `package.json`, change the *start* and *build* script as such:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, wherever you have been using the API URL:

**Example**

```js
axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/your/path`) // or any other way to join URL and path
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Hope it helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From all your `routes` remove `localhost:8080` and make direct request to `/api/` because everything is running under one PORT which is `5000`. You might need to re-build your front-end with changes made